# jQuery autocomplete not working in IE on page load

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have looked and looked and have not found anything.  I have an auto complete that works in FF but not in IE.  Looked for trailing commas and everything.

Error in IE on page load:

> Unable to get value of the property 'length': object is null or undefined 
>   jquery.js.php, line 723 character 4

Code:

```
$.ajax({  
    url: "lender-options.php",  
    dataType: "json"

}).done(function (source) {
    var lenders = $.map(source, function (value, key) { 
        return { 
            value: value, 
            data: key 
        }; 
    });

    $('#query').autocomplete({
        lookup: lenders,    
        width:400,
        appendTo: '#suggestions-container'
    });
});
```

Comment: What's the `lookup` property? Is this jQueryUI's autocomplete widget?

Comment: Ah no sorry about the lack of clarification.  This is https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete plugin.  Works great and fast with the exception of IE.

Comment: I believe the issue lies in :var lenders = $.map(source, function (value, key) { 
        return { 
            value: value, 
            data: key 
        }; 
    });

Comment: if it helps, doesnt help me at all.  On my php side, i am json encoding the array.  I am echoing that out.  Copying the string and pasting into a plain text file and running my ajax against that file to get the data.  Works perfectly.  When changing the ajax url to go back to the dynamic script (still echoing out the json encoded array) it breaks in IE again....  I don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in fact the headers.  After viewing the header info where it was working, it showed as plain/txt.  Changing the headers worked.

Answer (score 0):

As the ajax call returning an empty set?  Is it sending the correct headers?  I don't know, just reading through what I found here:  http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-autocomplete-problems-on-ie-6-and-ie-7

Comment: The ajax response is returning a json encoded array with tons of data.  Yes, this is working in FF.  As for the headers, I will look into.